# Using wireless printer as wired

Tags: printer

Does anyone know of a way to use a wireless printer as a wired printer.  The network I am connected to does not allow wireless printing.  I have an HP envy 4500 all-in-one printer.  Please let me know!

Comment: Does your printer have a USB connection option?

Comment: If the printer is only a wireless printer, then no, you cannot use a wireless printer other then through a wireless printer.  Check the manual for the printer on how to use other connection capabilities of it.

Comment: AT Ramhound, if you want to say something is impossible, you should provide a reason.  If it works like a wireless access point then maybe it's possible to connect a Pi to it wirelessly thereby effectively converting the wireless to wired.

Comment: From the looks of things / similar things https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WMmP4IcvEE  your terminology might not be correct. It looks like maybe the way it works is your connect to it wirelessly then it's part of the network then it's just network printing.. So if you can print over a network then whether a computer is connected wired or wirelessly shouldn't matter. I don't know whether the printer works as a wireless access point or wireless client but it might not matter.  Maybe it's a wireless access point and a different subnet you can't access, maybe that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

#### The network I am connected to does not allow wireless printing

The HP ENVY 4500 e-All-in-One Printer has a USB connection (but no ethernet connection).

Connect to a PC using USB and share the printer on the network if necessary.

[image]

Source [Printer Specifications for the HP ENVY 4500 and HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3540 Printers](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03755986)

Comment: Do you know where I can purchase one of these cords?

Comment: 4$ (including shipping) at Amazon [10ft ReadyPlug® USB Cable for HP Envy 4500 Wireless Color Photo Printer with Scanner and Copier](http://www.amazon.com/ReadyPlug%C2%AE-Cable-Wireless-Printer-Scanner/dp/B00FJF8KQ2)

Comment: Alternately, if you don't want to attach an entire PC to it, you may be able to use a device like this: http://www.iogear.com/product/GPSU21/

Comment: I take back my previous comment.  The page for that product explicitly states that it doesn't work for multi-function printers.   It might, in fact, be able to provide basic print functionality, but won't work with the scanning function.  (the lack of ability to use the other features, besides printing is likely also true for the PC sharing solution)

Comment: @bobbypin try going down to your local high street and asking anybody you see. Asking where you can buy a usb cable is like asking where you can buy a knife and fork, it's an every day item.

Answer (score -1):

Use an **USB-to-Ethernet Print Server**, like this one:

[image]

The USB port connects directly to the printer and the Ethernet port lets you connect to a cabled Ethernet network.  There are some models that also let you connect to a wireless network (to make a USB-*only* printer wireless), but in your case you don't need that functionality.

Search for "USB to Ethernet Print Server" and you should find a wide variety of devices for less than $50.00 USD.

Comment: Be careful with usb-ethernet print servers for low cost printers. Do not buy one unless its "compatibility list" includes your printer.

Comment: @hdhondt Good point. I've found that most HP printers work well with quality print server brands such as TrendNet or StarTech. I've had more trouble with other brand printers, especially ones that use host-based drivers.

Comment: Host-based is the problem, and most low-cost printers, including HP are just that. HP add to the confusion by having "PCL3" which is host-based and bears no relation to PCL5/6.